# What does the phrase "is of the now" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, vocabulary

I found this phrase in a Vogue article:

> His style, with its healthy punch of dork factor, **is of the now** in a way that is similar to Post Malone’s very self-aware, disheveled, sleazy look.

https://www.vogue.com/article/bad-bunny-style-overalls-sunglasses-gucci?utm_brand=vogue&mbid=social_facebook&utm_source=facebook&utm_social-type=owned&utm_medium=social&fbclid=IwAR3lZ1g9nH2L72FqqhnBHFCyGq4R_RS9g-t7XSqePKepC_Aag1Y_FKUYqTk

I googled it and found 17 matches, which I do not trust entirely.
Also, can we use definitive article in front of the word "now"?
Does it sound natural?

Comment: Do you have the link to that article ([edit] it in)? It's obviously a very distinctive writer/columnist style.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase **of the now** means the same as the French *au courant*, that is, fashionable, contemporary in its style, having the very latest look, trendy.

In the world of trendy fashion, yesterday is ancient history.

Yes, we can say **the now** to mean "the present".